# Finding the length of the arc.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, arc-length

Find the arc length of

$$r\langle t\rangle = \langle e^{t^2},3e^{t^2}-2,\frac{3}{2}e^{t^2}\rangle\text{ for } 0\le t\le 1$$

My try:

Arc length $= \int | r^1 (t) | \, dt$

$$ r^1(t) = \langle 2te^{t^2}, 6te^{t^2}, 3te^{t^2} \rangle $$

$$ |r^1(t)| = \sqrt{49t^2 e^{2t^2}} = 7te^{t^2}$$

Arc length $\displaystyle = \int_0^1 7te^{t^2} \, dt = \dfrac 7 2 (e - 1)$

Is my above attempt correct? Can anyone please verify.

Comment: Proper notation is $r\langle t\rangle = \cdots,$ not $r<t>= \cdots.$ I edited accordingly.

Comment: Correct to me!.

Comment: Yup! Is r^1 supposed to be r'

Comment: This is well done !